# Spigot Plugin Command only for command blocks doesnt output anything or give any errors

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have this command only to be executed when used in a command block. When I use it in a command block, it doesn't output any errors, and it doesn't output an error in the console.

```
import net.md_5.bungee.api.chat.ClickEvent;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.chat.TextComponent;
import net.md_5.bungee.api.ChatColor;
import static org.bukkit.Bukkit.getServer;
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.command.BlockCommandSender;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;


public class attractie implements CommandExecutor {

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {

        if(sender instanceof BlockCommandSender) {
            BlockCommandSender commandblock = (BlockCommandSender) sender;
            if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("attractie"))
            {
                String temp = String.join(" ", args);
                temp = ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', temp);
                // Old broadcast // Bukkit.getServer().spigot().broadcast("§7[§dInfo§7] " + ChatColor.BLUE + "De " + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + args[1] + ChatColor.BLUE + " Is geopend!" + ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + " [Klik hier om te warpen]"); //broadcast wel maar is volgens mij niet clickable.
                TextComponent message = new TextComponent(ChatColor.GRAY + "[" + ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "Info" + ChatColor.GRAY + "]" + ChatColor.BLUE + "De " + ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + args[1] + args[2] + args[3] + args[4] +args[5] + ChatColor.BLUE + " Is geopend!" + ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + " [Klik hier om te warpen]");
                message.setColor(ChatColor.RED);
                message.setClickEvent(new ClickEvent(ClickEvent.Action.RUN_COMMAND, "/warp " + args[0]));
                getServer().getOnlinePlayers().forEach(player -> player.spigot().sendMessage(message));
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show where you register your `CommandExecutor`?

Comment: Small tip, you shouldn't create your TextComponent like you do. If you want to use the ChatColor with string concatenation you should use the static method TextComponent.fromLegacyText() to create a TextComponent instance. I would recomment to use the ComponentBuilder instead as described here: https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/the-chat-component-api/ .